# reassign value to query string parameter

Tags: c#, query-string

I have a "showall" query string parameter in the url, the parameter is being added dynamically when "Show All/Show Pages" button is clicked.

I want the ability to toggle "showall" query string parameter value depending on user clicking the "Show All/Show Pages" button.

I'm doing some nested "if's" and `string.Replace()` on the url, is there a better way?

All manipulations are done on the server.

**p.s.** Toran, good suggestion, however I HAVE TO USE URL PARAMETER due to some other issues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to elaborate on Toran's answer:

Use:
    `<asp:HiddenField ID="ShowAll" Value="False" runat="server" />`

To toggle your state:

```
protected void ToggleState(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //parse string as boolean, invert, and convert back to string
    ShowAll.Value = (!Boolean.Parse(ShowAll.Value)).ToString();
}
```

Comment: accepted this over Toran's just because i had no idea that <asp:HiddenField> existed. always used <input type="hidden" />

Answer (score 0):

Another dirty alternative could be just to use a hidden input and set that on/off instead of manipulating the url.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be too much of an effort just to have the value hard-coded into the URL (I know it's not too nice) with a default value or true then just have

`booleanVar = !booleanVar;`

run on every page load?

At least that would move away from the need of having nested ifs to manipulate the URL.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure based upon the question, but isn't this where [HTTPHandlers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms227675(VS.80).aspx) come to the rescue? Shouldn't you be handling the variable alteration on the object prior to page rendering in this case then?